# Manipular classes com jQuery / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dentro da hierarquia abaixo, como posso manipular uma classe dada ao `<th>` após clicar em um elemento dentro da `<td>`? Lembrando que existem diversas tabelas como essa.

```
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class=""></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tdody>
<table>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta atribuir um evento a cada `td`, vincular cada uma com seu `th` através das `classes`, e ao clicar subir no `dom` até a `table` para achar a respectiva `th`

isso de subir no `dom` só é necessário caso tenha mais de uma `table`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('table tbody tr td').each(function(el) {
   
   $(this).on('click', function(el) {
     alert( $(this).closest('table').find( "th."+$(this).attr('class') ).text() );
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th class="item1">th</th>
    <th class="item2">th1</th>
    <th class="item3">th2</th>
    <th class="item4">th3</th>
    <th class="item5">th4</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td class="item1">td</td>
     <td class="item2">td1</td>
     <td class="item3">td2</td>
     <td class="item4">td3</td>
     <td class="item5">td4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Isso mesmo Felipe! Valeu!

Comment: Denada!, não esqueça de selecionar a resposta que te ajudou como melhor, fica no canto superior esquerdo, abaixo dos votos, isso ajuda o site e outros usuários